# Sass Styling Isn't Displaying On Class

Tags: html, sass

I'm trying to style a few buttons using sass so they all look the same, but my style isn't displaying. I'm new to sass, so I'm guessing there's some syntax I'm overlooking. What do I need to change to make this start working? The buttons all have the same code.

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_base.css">
<button type="button" class="removeButton">Remove</button>
```

**_base.scss**

```
.removeButton {
    button:active {
        background: #dd4646;
    }
    button:focus {
        background: #dd4646;
    }
    button {
        background: #fb4e4e;
    }
    background: #fb4e4e;
}
```

Comment: `button:` should be `&:`

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the scss file to css. Link the css in html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your Sass to CSS.

For that you can use Gulp, Webpack o other.

If you want to use Gulp

```
npm i gulp-sass
```

Then in your Gulp file you can write something like:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

For more information, [check the npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass).

Answer (score 0):

Nesting your selectors translates to the descendant relationship. Basically

```
.removeButton {
  button:active {
      background: #dd4646;
  }
}
```

compiles to

```
.removeButton button:active {
    background: #dd4646;
}
```

Check your CSS output to verify. What you actually want is to connect them to select a single element. You can do that by using the `&`character. [See the docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_rules#parent-selector)

```
.removeButton {
  &:active {
    background: #dd4646;
  }
}
```

`&` means to match the parent selector. Replace all your occurrences of `button` with `&` and you should be fine.